# Can't access global variable from form in Visual C++ forms application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, global-variables

Program description: reading and displaying data from XML
OS: Windows 7
IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express

I have this code segment in my main source file(*BABSEA CLE Library.cpp*):

```
int currentBook;
#include "Editor.h"
#include "checkoutline.h"
#include "Form1.h"
using namespace BABSEACLELibrary;
[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
//more code blablabla
```

And I try to access "currentBook" from the (not main) form (*checkoutline.h*), which is a simple form template with this piece added to it:

```
        private: System::Void checkoutline_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
currentBook=0;}
```

Though it works perfectly in the main form file (*Form1.h*)

Any ideas?

Comment: This will not work unless `checkoutline.h` includes `Library.cpp` which in turn doesn't make sense.

Comment: Take 5 minutes and think about it :)

Comment: There's probably another .cpp file in your project, like "checkoutline.cpp", that also #includes checkoutline.h.  Which of course isn't going to see that global variable.  The standard C++ hassle is to declare the global variable as extern in a .h file.  Or remove that .cpp file if it is empty.  Or declare the variable as a static member of the class.  Or create winform forms in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I removed

```
#include "checkoutline.h"
```

from checkoutline.cpp

It's all good. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you're not understanding what the issue really is and are not learning proper style.

Your header file should declare any classes, functions, variables that are defined in your implementation file.